# How to retrieve all DNS records using PowerShell without DnsServer module?

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-7

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2. Every post I find suggests using DnsServer module for Powershell, but it is not supported for these machines. So how else can I get these records? I am trying to export them to a CSV file. "nslookup" doesn't really do the trick.

Comment: There's a DNSShell module for PS which predates the DNS server module - if you can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the...

> I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2. Every post I find suggests using
>   DnsServer module for Powershell, but it is not supported for these
>   machines.

... that, is not a valid statement. They are supported on Win7 and W2K8. Heck, you could use them on Vista - as documented per Microsoft.

> [Description of Windows Server 2008 Remote Server Administration Tools
>   for Windows Vista Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941314/description-of-windows-server-2008-remote-server-administration-tools)
>
> System requirements
>
> RSAT can be installed on 32-bit and 64-bit editions of the following
>   configurations: Windows Vista Ultimate with SP1 or a later Windows
>   Vista service pack

- Windows Vista Enterprise with SP1 or a later Windows Vista service pack
- Windows Vista Business with SP1 or a later Windows Vista service pack
- RSAT can be used to manage 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008.

> RSAT should not be installed on a computer that is running the Windows
>   Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack or the Windows 2000 Server
>   Administration Tools Pack. Please remove all Administration Tools Pack
>   versions from the computer before you install RSAT.
>
> Only one copy of RSAT can be installed on a computer at one time.
>   Before you install a new package, remove any existing versions of
>   RSAT. This includes any copies that are in different languages.

You need to install the RAT tools on your Win7 host, you have to enable them on W2K8/R2.

> [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1
>   (SP1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Actually, if that is not allowed. You don't need to install the RSAT tools, you can proxy them from any DC or server running RSAT to your workstation. This is a very common practice, it's called implicit remoting and well documented in plenty of resources all over the web. Otherwise, you need to use ADSI, the .Net libraries...

> [Dns.GetHostEntry Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netframework-4.8)
>
> [Dns.GetHostByAddress Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostbyaddress?view=netframework-4.8)

```
# The following code returns the IPv4 address of a given alias or host: 
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('someDnsName').IPAddressToString

# The below code returns the HostName (CName) and aliases of an IP: 
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress('172.12.34.56')

$name = 'someName'
$fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($name).HostName 
$ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($fqdn).IPAddressToString
$result = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip)
```

... or other 3rdP tools. Yet, if you use this 3rdP route, you may as well install the official RSAT on one of your machines.

A quick search using say, 'Use PowerShell Active Directory Cmdlets Without Installing', or 'windows 7 get dns records' will give you that list with samples.

> [Use PowerShell Active Directory Cmdlets Without Installing Any
>   Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-active-directory-cmdlets-without-installing-any-software)
>
> [Using AD module without loading RSAT](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd0b0a1c-b6dc-4657-8a95-21b6a11377df/using-ad-module-without-loading-rsat)

So, You can then use the following example to import the Active Directory cmdlets from a remote Windows Server 2008 R2 (either DC or member server or workstation with RSAT for AD installed):

```
$session = New-PSSession -computerName 'TargetMachineWithRsat'
Invoke-Command { Import-Module ActiveDirectory } -Session $session
Import-PSSession $session
```

An alternate way is to export the remote PowerShell session into a local module:

```
$session = New-PSSession -computerName 'TargetMachineWithRsat'
Invoke-Command { Import-Module ActiveDirectory } -Session $session
Export-PSSession -Session $session -CommandName *-AD* -Outputmodule ActiveDirectory -AllowClobber
```

Load the module using

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```